# Calling a php function from an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Code of ajax php page

```
 require_once("../include/config.php");
    $user=createuser(0);
    /*echo $user;*/
    $sql=("update utenti SET user='".$user."' , password='".hash("sha256","psw")."' , verifica=0 where id='".$_POST['res']."'");
    $query=$mysq->query($sql);  
    $message['error']=false;
    echo json_encode($message);
```

`config.php` function:

```
session_start();
$mysq= new mysqli('localhost','root','','psw');
function createuser($id){
    global $mysq;   
    if($id==0){
        $sql="select id from  utenti order by id DESC limit 1";
        $query=$mysq->query($sql);
        $row=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $id=$row['id'];
    }
    $user="scuola".$id;     
    $sql="select user from  utenti where user='".$user."'";
    $query=$mysq->query($sql);      
    if($query->num_rows){
        createuser($id+1);
    }else{
        /*echo $user;*/
        return $user;       
    }   
}
```

So when I call `createuser(0)` in the ajax page the echo is empty but if I print the variable user before the return it gave me the right result.
I see the echo on F12 of Chrome but I commented the `echo` out now because the result of ajax is only JSON.
I also noticed that if I changed the return with simple return "c" the user in ajax page was still empty.

EDIT add the js script there isn't any relevant html

```
$('.reset').click(function(){       
            var reset=$(this).attr("data-us");          
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../ajax/ajax-user.php",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    res: reset /*id of user to reset*/
                },
                success: function (data) {  
                    if (data.error == true) {
                        $("#notice").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                        $("#notice").html('...' + data.message + '...');
                    } else {            
                        $("#notice").removeClass("alert alert-danger").addClass("alert alert-success");
                        location.reload();                     
                    }
                },
                error: function (e, t, n) {
                    $("#notice").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                    $("#notice").html('Qualcosa non va, chiamata ajax fallita....'+t+'........'+n+'....');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Try adding this `$message['user'] = $user` before echoing the json?

Comment: I don't need to pass the $user trough the ajax but i need only to make the sql query, i wrote in the title ajax becaouse in the other pages all the function works      EDIT i call the function on other normal php page and print nothing but into the function $user exist and is correct

Comment: @Ruggero where is the HTML and the javascript?

Comment: I think it wasn't important because the problem is with the php function, but i can add the code in the question

Comment: When you call `createuser($id+1);` you not returning anything, try `return createuser($id+1);`. That can be the problem.

Comment: oh yeah even without trying i'm sure you are right, i don't know why i didn't see it before, thanks!